# ImageView with camera button at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am new to android. I have an imageview with camera button at bottom of image view. Whenever the button is clicked,camera should open and capture image.This captured image should be saved in memory and imageview must now display this captured image .Whenver the camera button is clicked,new image must be saved and imageview must display this image. [image: Layout]

How to design this type of layout with camera button as placed at the bottom of image view?

Comment: This is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well You can use this layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bicycle" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

you can use Intent to choose an image from gallery or from camera

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, KEY);
            \\KEY is final String with any value
        }
    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

check the follwing example 
http://www.android-examples.com/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-imageview-android/

Comment: i just wanted to know how to create the given layout...i can create image view but how to place the camera button as placed in the pic.....can you give the xml layout?

Comment: unrelated answer